# Редактирование статуса на лету

Tags: jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте!

Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать редактирование статуса, подобное, как ВКонтакте, т.е. ссылка в виде текста, по клику на которую вызывается всплывающее текстовое поле (input, textarea) с возможностью редактирования и кнопкой, при клике на которую и происходит сохранение нового статуса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**html:**

```
<div id="status_change">
    <p id="status">Статус</p>
    <div id="status_cotainer_change">
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="status_val">
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top:7px;">
            <button id="save_status">Сохранить</button>
        </div
        <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**js:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // open
    $('#status').click(function(){
        $('#status_val').val($('#status').text());
        $('#status_cotainer_change').show();
    });

    // save
    $('#save_status').click(function(){
        $('#status').text($.trim($('#status_val').val()))
        $('#status_cotainer_change').hide();
    });
});
```

Как-то так: http://jsfiddle.net/qme344a6/1/

Comment: Большое спасибо! Жаль, но не хватает репы отблагодарить..!

Answer (score 2):

Я ни на что не намекаю. http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/contenteditable